# Is it possible to remove Snapd with Glib libraries completely without ruining the system?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, snap, 21.10

I have just installed Ubuntu MATE 21.10 and discovered two interesting packages which contain `snapd` in the name - *gir1.2-snapd-1* and *libsnapd-glib1*:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep snapd
ii  gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64                     1.58-0ubuntu2                       amd64        Typelib file for libsnapd-glib1
ii  libsnapd-glib1:amd64                     1.58-0ubuntu2                       amd64        GLib snapd library
```

Both came from [snapd-glib](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/impish/snapd-glib) package.

Removal of them will ruin the system as follows:

```
$ sudo apt autopurge gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64 libsnapd-glib1:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apturl* apturl-common* ayatana-indicator-sound* bluez-cups* cups* cups-browsed* cups-core-drivers* cups-daemon* cups-server-common*
  gir1.2-goa-1.0* gir1.2-snapd-1* hplip* hplip-data* libcanberra-pulse* libcupsimage2* libgutenprint-common* libgutenprint9* libhpmud0*
  libimagequant0* libpulsedsp* libsane-hpaio* libsbc1* libsnapd-glib1* libspeexdsp1* printer-driver-gutenprint* printer-driver-hpcups*
  printer-driver-postscript-hp* printer-driver-splix* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-utils* python3-dateutil* python3-debconf*
  python3-olefile* python3-pil* python3-renderpm* python3-reportlab* python3-reportlab-accel* python3-software-properties* rtkit*
  software-properties-common* software-properties-gtk* ssl-cert* ubuntu-mate-core* ubuntu-mate-desktop* ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk* update-manager*
  update-notifier* update-notifier-common*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 49 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 49,3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Is it possible to remove *gir1.2-snapd-1* and *libsnapd-glib1* packages without ruining the system?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a particular reason that you want to remove those 2 particular packages?  Are they causing problems?

Comment: So I just ran that same command, I'm running 20.04.  The command returns different output specific to 20.04, but they are clearly base packages, personally I do not recommend removing base packages for any reason.  I tried a locate of specific files, no way I would ever think of dong this myself, so I wouldn't tell anyone else EVER to do such a thing.

Comment: I have no clue what the snap developers are trying to achieve. Now, even packages for sound, bluetooth and printing depend on things related to snapd.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi they are desperately trying to keep people from removing it. If it gets to the point that I can't remove it without breaking the system, it's goodbye Ubuntu.  So far 20.04 is OK.

Comment: So snap seems to be a new thing in 20.04, I wonder if there's a way to revert it back by removing `snapd` and replacing it with the "original packages" whatever they were.  If you could find a previous version and compare the packages between the two distros. 
That's something else I would try if I were in a jam and wanted try something for myself.  Again only in test/virtual environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These packages are designed to allow applications to communicate with snapd. One accordingly would believe that these packages are not of any use of `snapd` is not anymore installed. However, in order for an app to be able to communicate with `snapd`, the app must be compiled with support for these libraries. These libraries thus become a hard dependency of these apps, and must stay on the system even if `snapd` is removed.

That is the technical reason. However, what functionality (non-snap) applications gain by being able to access `snapd` is unclear. All descriptions of what the libraries do boil down to

> snapd-glib is a library to allow GLib based applications access to
> snapd, the daemon that controls Snaps.

Possibly, these are what would allow these apps to access to the [Snapd REST API](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapd-api) in order to interact with `snapd`.

Answer (score -3):

## remove snap

Find installed snaps: `snap list`

Remove installed snaps: `sudo snap remove <package>`

Remove snapd: `sudo apt purge snapd`

Remove snap directory from home:  `rm -rf ~/snap`

If you receive an error removing snapd then do the following : `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd then run sudo apt purge snapd`